# How to write a CSV and store it as a string in JRI?

Tags: java, r, csv, export-to-csv, jri

I am looking for a way to store CSV formatted text into a string in JRI (Java/R Interface). Currently, the only way I know for dealing with writing CSV files is:

```
write.csv(MyData, file = "MyData.csv")
```

Which formats `MyData` into CSV and writes it to a CSV file. My application, though, does not use files so I need to set the output of `write.csv` to a variable instead of a file.

I have tried this code snippet that, according to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/0.1.1/topics/write_csv), just formats a `data.frame` to a string.

```
REXP s = Rutils.rengine.eval("write_csv(foo, sep = ',', quote = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)");
System.out.println(s);
```

being `Rutils` the class where I store my `Rengine` and `foo` the data frame I try to format (which contains association rules extracted from `arules`' `apriori` function.

However, I get `null` as my output every time I run the file.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: *"What I want is to write to a string variable "* I don't understand what that means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: *"I need to set the output of write.csv to a variable instead of a file"* Sorry that's still not clear to me. `write.csv` writes the contents of a `data.frame` to a file. The `data.frame` is your R object. Perhaps you should provide a more representative code example that demonstrates what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: So for your example you could do `csv_content <- capture.output(write.csv(MyData, file = stdout()))`

Comment: @MauritsEvers Edited the question with some more code.

Comment: @amatsuo_net It's not working. I still get ```null``` in my Java output.

Comment: Then what about `Rutils.rengine.eval("capture.output(write.csv(MyData, file = stdout()))");
System.out.println(s)`?

Comment: @amatsuo_net ```null``` too. :(

Comment: I don't have an environment to test but `REXP s = Rutils.rengine.eval("capture.output(write.csv(MyData, file = stdout()))"); System.out.println(s.asString());` still doesn't work?